# Transform Callback into Observable with data from other Observable

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to RxJava and I got a question about transforming callbacks into Observables.

I have this function that uses a callback.

```
client.loadAsync(body, object : Callback {
   override fun onSuccess(response: AwesomeResponse) {
      // Successful response!
   }
   
   override fun onError(exception: Exception) {
      // Error response!
   }
})
```

For this, I use `Single.create`

```
Single.create {
   client.loadAsync(body, object : Callback {
      override fun onSuccess(response: AwesomeResponse) {
         it.onSuccess(response)
      }
   
      override fun onError(exception: Exception) {
         it.onError(exception)
      }
   })
}
```

The problem comes from the `body` parameter, to build it I need data from another observable.

This is what I'm doing right now.

```
otherObservable.doOnNext { dto -> 
   val body = clientBody(id = dto.Id)

   Single.create {
      client.loadAsync(body, object : Callback {
         override fun onSuccess(response: AwesomeResponse) {
            it.onSuccess(response)
         }

         override fun onError(exception: Exception) {
            it.onError(exception)
         }
      })
   }
   .subscribeOn(scheduler)
   .subscribe(
      { uiReportSubject.onNext(it) }, 
      {}, 
      compositeDisposable
   )
}
.subscribeOn(scheduler)
.subscribe()
```

I'm receiving the data into my UI through the subscription of the `uiReportSubject` object which is a `BehaviourSubject`

My question is, is this the right way to do this? or is there a better way to do this? Like an operator (like `map`) or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Use `otherObservable.flatMap(dto -> ... return Single.create(...))`.

Comment: It wont let me. the IDE reports this:

Type mismatch:

Required: ObservableSource<out Item>

Found: Single<Item>

Im using RxJava3. is the RxJava version relevant?

Comment: I changed Single.create to Observable.create and it accepts the return type now. I'll test it out

Comment: Then its `flatMapSingle`.